# Sharepoint search with 'this site' suffix

Tags: html, sharepoint, search

I'm trying to create a team site (which is mostly links to other sources) in HTML with CSS. That part is going fine, but I would like to integrate a search of our SharePoint site, it includes 000s of documents that'd be great to make more accessible.

Found:

```
<form method="get" action="<SharePoint-search-results-page-URL>">
<input name="k" type="text" />
<input name="Search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/02/16/how-to-create-a-html-search-box-for-sharepoint-search.aspx)

This is working, but the way our Sharepoint is setup I am actually searching the whole database of files, not just our subsite. I have tried changing the URL so that it includes the sc and u flags, this will bring me to the same results, but have a 'this site' dropdown.

How can I concatenate the search url with the correct suffix when I submit the search?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the MS Sharepoint version and relevant configurations performed.

Comment: It's sharepoint 2010, was able to just do a random search (e.g. 'asdf'), from any of our sharepoint pages or libraries. Then take the url from before that